# Page Scroll com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer um `page scroll` quando clico em um link do meu navbar, só que quando eu clico obtenho o seguinte erro no console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  setBindings();
});


function setBindings() {
  $("nav a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
}
```

Não estou entendendo, eu sou leigo com `javascript` o código foi de um vídeo que eu vi no **Youtube**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola amigo tenta verificar a versão do jquery que você esta usando, montei um que pega o top do paragrafo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert("Top: " + $("p").offset().top);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<p>paragrafo</p>
<button>Clicar</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu tinha até desistido, era a versão do jquery mesmo.